# Grafana custom editor for every query/series

Tags: reactjs, typescript, elasticsearch, grafana, observability

I was wondering if it is possible to write a custom editor (StandardEditorProps) that displays multiple input fields dynamically for every query (every series in the dataFrame).
I would need the same form (labels, bunch of select and text input fields) repeated for every query (I need to get the field names of the query resultset).
These values will be then used to render the custom panel plugin.

If I return, in StandardEditorProps, the entire form, then onChange every select input field is updated with the same value and I cant get the value of every input field in the custom panel plugin as only one customEditor is added in the module.tsx.

On the other hand, If I define multiple custom (and others non custom) editors in module.tsx I can get the values in the panel plugin but I cant make N such forms dynamically.

Hope that makes sense.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas how achieve that?